# Handle apple-reference-documentation:// url scheme in web view

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoa, wkwebview

I want to show some apple documentation references e.g. [NSTableView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nstableview).
in an app.

I know, `NSTableView` for example, is located at *apple-reference-documentation://hs_JTB0H3I*. If I load an `URLRequest` with such an `URL` in an `WKWebView` instance Xcode opens its Documentation Browser and shows the document.

Can someone help me to show the url in my app and not in the Xcode documentation browser.

Code below:

```
let path = "apple-reference-documentation://hsCsDTDolH"
if let url = URL(string: path) {
    let request = URLRequest(url: url)
    webView.load(request) // webView is WKWebView
}
```

Comment: I don't find anything related to 'hsCsDTDolH or 'apple-reference-documentation' in my local system.

Comment: Yeah, I know there might not be such a file in the local system. But if you search for apple-reference-documentation://hs_JTB0H3I in safari, you are asked if you want to allow this page to open Xcode.app. If you agree, the documentation file is shown in Xcode's documentation browser.

Comment: So, I was asking if there is a way to get the data from Xcode's documentation browser or if there is an application/tool inside Xcode.app to fetch this data.

Comment: I was looking for a solution to view Xcode docs in some kind of view in my app, but ended up using links to Apple's website. I found some resources which may in some time lead to a way to do it. First, look at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DNTDocumentationSupport.framework/Resources/external/index.docsindex - this seems to contain a list of links to doc pages, for example apple-reference-documentation://cccallkit is for CallKit in Obj-C and apple-reference-documentation://cscallkit for CallKit in Swift. How to use this info and display the docs in a view -no solution yet.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is not a way to read the data from Xcode's documentation browser (that would destroy the separation that exists between apps). No, there is not a separate app or tool in Xcode that fetches the docs, it is part of the code within Xcode itself.

`apple-reference-documentation://` is a custom URL scheme that Xcode says it can handle (see a brief explanation [here](http://fredandrandall.com/blog/2011/07/30/how-to-launch-your-macios-app-with-a-custom-url/)). Xcode then uses the rest of the URL to figure out what page to pull from the developer site and display.

In order to hijack this URL scheme you would have to set your app up as capable of handling it, figure out how Xcode determines that `hs_JTB0H3I` means `https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nstableview`, open the correct webpage and then get the system to let your app open the `apple-reference-documentation://` links rather than Xcode (there likely isn't an easy way if one exists at all).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But Xcode refers not to the website. It works offline as well, therefore Xcode gets the documentation page from its app contents I think. Maybe there is a command line tool to extract the information from disk?